# execution/reading issue on vm box run by linux and provisioned by chef

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra

Sorry for the bad title but I can't think what to call the problem.

Right, so I've decided to move from windows to linux to solve an issue but now I'm encountering something else. 
When I provision with vagrant and it tries to start my app it says `require': cannot load such file - /usr/
local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gem_name-version/lib/gem_name/info` So I ssh'ed into the box and went to the folder and well, I'ts odd. I'f I do `ls -l` I get a list of files including the one it supposedly can't find exactly where I expect it to be (`lib/gem_name/info`) but here's the thing I can't actually CD into the directory `/lib/gem_name` but if can do `cat lib\\gem_name\\info.rb` and the file content displays.

The permissions for all the files are:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`

and the executable is:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root`

I'm not sure what to do to fix this, why can't it find or use the files?

EDIT: I've changed the execute resource to to have `user "root"` but it's still winging about not being able to find the folder

I'd also like to mention that whilst `lib\boot.rb` exists `lib` the folder doesn't according to `ls -l` even if I do `sudo ls -l` it still doesn't display `lib` the folder, only `lib`'s contents.

EDIT:
I'd also like to mention that the `bin` folder exists and displays as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those that answered thanks but I worked it out, in the move to linux I forgot to remove a bit of code that changed all `/` to `\\` which meant in linux it created a file called `lib\app_name\info.rb` instead of `info.rb` inside of the folder `lib/app_name`. So in future kids, remember to make sure your pathing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is the root cause of your problem.  Root is the superuser, and if root owns a file and has not granted access to other users, they can read it but not execute it.  Directories require execution privileges if you wish to cd into them.

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root

Vagrant does not run as root.  You need to give the vagrant user access to /usr/local/lib/ruby, and the easiest way you can do this is:

1. ssh into the system as root
2. issue the command `chown -R vagrant:vagrant /usr/local/lib/ruby`

This changes the owner of /usr/local/lib/ruby to vagrant, so in general you wouldn't do this on a normal server, but given this is a virtual box and you're using vagrant it's ok to do it here.

Comment: hmm I have to do it via chef as once I get this running on vagrant I intend to get this onto a production box and we don't get ssh access to production boxes. I did infact try this as a user specially created to run/own my app BUT the're are two issues with this, one) ruby_build fails when I try to do it as any other user and two) I can't install the gem as a specific user.

Comment: `chown -R vagrant:vagrant /` would be even better! Actually I'd change chmod.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting some really odd permissions on `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gem_name-version/lib/gem_name/info`, especially if `root` can't even see it.  You can confirm that by doing an `ls -al` on the parent directory.  You could fix it with a `directory` chef resource with proper permissions, but you really should chase down the root cause of the permissions being so out of whack.